# Create a HTML project in GitLab

Tags: html, github, gitlab

I am trying to host a static web page in gitlab. But the problem is that the main page appears in a url like this:
https://anycustomname.gitlab.io/tutorials/

But I don't want the /tutorials/ at the end of the URL.
I want people to visit my website by entering the following:
https://anycustomname.gitlab.io

And not this:
https://anycustomname.gitlab.io/tutorials

I know it is possible.
I just don't know how to configure this.
Google and YouTube were not much of a help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_one.html).

You need to name your project `anycustomname.gitlab.io` instead of `tutorials`.